# How do i enable hinting for streaming in mp4 files?

Tags: video, file-format, mp4, video-conversion

I have used MP4Box in the past to enable hinting on mp4 files in the past but it looks like its no longer in the repositories. Is there anything else that can be used or do i need to compile from source?

Comment: Search in packages.ubuntu.com for it, in the repositories for previous versions of ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the `gpac` package.

Click the red button to easily install it with the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

---

Or install it with the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gpac
```

(Thanks to @uri-herrera!)